# Use css or javascript to prevent the url from being printed when the webpage is printed?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, printing-web-page

In terms of browsers, I have in mind Firefox and Chrome.

I have a webpage that users typically print.  I would like to suppress the url (or, ideally, the entire header and footer) from being printed, regardless of the print settings/page setup the user has specified.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Most print settings are simply not exposed to the script.